# Firebase auth onUpdate cloud function for when a user updates their email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I need to run a Firebase function whenever my user updates their email address, except auth only has onCreate and onDelete. How can I react to email updates?

Comment: At this point I believe Firebase is defunct and the alternatives available are vastly superior. Even if they add new features, the fact the architecture is extremely opinionated and forces lock-in to Google makes the project a bad choice for new and existing users. Personally, I now use Supabase and to me it’s clearly the better choice instead of Firebase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible today to *directly* react to an email address changing in Firebase Authentication.  If you'd like to see that as a feature, please file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

You can react to it *indirectly* by having your app listen to authentication events ([Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener))), take the [User object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users) delivered to your listener, and write the user's email address to a RealtimeDatabase location (or Firestore document) for that user's UID.  Then, you can have a [database trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) that tracks the location of your users in the database, and react to the change there.

Comment: Wondering if there has been any updated on this now that it's 2020

Comment: @tazmaniax Looks like onCreate and onDelete are the only 2 public functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_auth_.userbuilder#methods

Comment: So frustrating, having a function onUpdate opens up a lot of options.

Comment: It's extremely frustrating that this hasn't been implemented. I submitted a feature request for it about a year ago and at that time received the following response:

`Upon checking on our end, there's an internal feature request filed to have an onUpdate() method for Authentication. However, I cannot guarantee as to when this feature will be officially rolled out.`

Feels like this feature should be a no-brainer...

Comment: I also submitted a feature request for an onUpdate function and received this: `There is no timeline I can share on when this feature will come out, but for now, you can keep an eye out for updates on our` [official blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/) `and` [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases)`.` Hoping this will be implemented soon!

Answer (score -1):

My Workaround Use functions.https.onCall to create an HTTPS callable function.

### Firebase Function

```
exports.onUpdateUserEmail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const uid = context.auth.uid;
  const email = context.auth.token.email || null;
  return admin.
      firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uid)
      .set({email});
});
```

### Deploy

$ firebase deploy --only functions:addMessage

### Call your Fonction in your app nodejs example firebase v9

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, updateEmail } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from 'firebase/functions';

 const app = initializeApp({
     projectId: '### CLOUD FUNCTIONS PROJECT ID ###',
     apiKey: '### FIREBASE API KEY ###',
     authDomain: '### FIREBASE AUTH DOMAIN ###',
   });
   const functions = getFunctions(app);
   const onUpdateEmail = httpsCallable(functions, 'onUpdateUserEmail');
   const auth = getAuth();
   updateEmail(auth.currentUser, "user@example.com").then(() => {
   // Email updated!
      onUpdateEmail();
   }).catch((error) => {
   // An error occurred
   // ...
});
```

Comment: While this might work for you, the main issue is that it’s not a trigger. If you had multiple apps and a website then you need to copy this code across all platforms and you will need to ensure the code works 100% as the email is critical user data. Calling a custom function is always an option, but it’s insecure and unreliable.

Comment: I have since abandoned Firebase and I now use Supabase.