# Firebase cloud function listener for password change

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Couldn't find it in the Firebase docs but is there a listener for when a password is changed like there is for when an account is created?

```
functions.auth.user().onCreate
```

Goal: Sending an email to the user that his/her password has been changed in the web app.

Comment: this trigger would be handy in some situations...

Answer (score 0):

No, [there is no trigger for Firebase Auth account updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933827/firebase-auth-onupdate-cloud-function-for-when-a-user-updates-their-email).  Feel free to [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features).