# How to make user's password expire using firebase API?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a mobile app that uses firebase's mail/password authentication.

The accounts are created by someone with a "manager" profile and distributed to all their employees. The accounts use their personal corporative mails and the first password is the employee ID. For security reasons, I want to force the employees to change their password the first time they log in and then once every 30 days. Is there any way to implement this using firebase's API? Sort of like defining an expire date. Or do I have to manually do the checks keeping track of the last time the password was changed?

Comment: That's not possible out of the box with firebase authentication. I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58082049/how-to-trigger-a-cloud-function-in-firebase-on-password-change) could help you. You'll also have to store the password's last modified date in a database and check that periodically to send user an email. All of that has to be managed by cloud functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no configuration that you can set that will force password changes.

You will have to somehow force this on your own by writing application code to keep track of the last time it was successfully changed, and disallowing use of your app if it wasn't change within some threshold of time.